# Downloading Rails 2.0 ,error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to download rails, it's giving me an error in the command prompt when trying to get it downloaded.

I have up until:

```
cd C:\Ruby193\Devkit
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install
```

Done, but when I try to add this last line:

```
gem install rails --install-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

I get an error that says "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --include-dependencies"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using Rails 2.0?  4.0 was just released, and support for versions of Rails below 3 seems to be slowly dropping away.

Comment: Oh wow.. didn't realize that. I'll have to redo it then, thanks for the help! Still new to Rails.

Comment: XD no problem.  Rails is great - I recommend the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl - he has a version for Rails 3 and idk if a version for Rails 4 has been put out yet, but it's excellent.

Comment: By the way, if you ran `gem install rails` as Debadatt recommended, it probably installed the latest.  Run `gem list` and check the version number by Rails - it's probably the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
gem install rails -include-dependencies -no-ri-no-rdoc
```